# User defined form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am creating a rails app wherein I have a problems model.
How do i create a form that asks the user to choose the range of values that he wants to see.
i.e the form asks him to choose say the cause of the problem and between what dates such problems could have occurred and then output those results from database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Dynamic Forms](https://github.com/chrisjpowers/dynamic_forms) a little while back but haven't had a chance to try it yet. It looks like it might be what you're chasing.